# Visual Studio : Language Service Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, service

I'm trying to compile a project I have in Visual Studio 2010. It has built fine on 2 other computers with Visual Studio, but on this computer, it will not compile, and returns:

**"The property could not be read/written because the language service returned an unknown error"**

Obviously, I have tried googling, and nothing of any use came up, so some help would be great.

Additional Information:

- Project is an XNA 4.0 Project
- Trying to deploy the solution to a Windows phone. The phone is plugged in, unlocked, etc. and other projects will deploy successfully to it.

Comment: Desperate measure: have you tryed reinstalling the Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the SDK, as other projects for it will compile and deploy to both the emulator and device fine.

Comment: Try creating an empty new solution, and add this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into the exact same error message when I tried editing the `AssemblyInfo.cs` using VS 2010's `Assembly Information` dialog from within the project properties (open `Properties` -> `Application` from below the given project).

As [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1588745.aspx/1) suggests, I deleted the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and filled in the values I wanted in the dialog box which created a new and working `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Maybe this would help/would have helped in your scenario as well.

Note, that you'll get a fresh and valid GUID if you simply click save after opening the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this today in VS 2017.  It went away as soon as I performed a build which fetched all my references.